# How can I set EC2 ownership permissions that allow me to update WordPress and modify files via FTP?

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, hosting, web-hosting

I have an AWS EC2 (Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type) on Apache with a working WordPress site on it.

If I run `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/html`, then I can edit files via SFTP and save them, but not update my plugins.

If I run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html`, then I can update my plugins but not edit files via SFTP and save them.

How can I update my plugins and edit my files without having to run the corresponding command each time?

I have already run `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html`.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions seems correct to me. Did you install a ftp server in the ec2 instance? 
As you don't mention that, I guess you will have to install one than use credentials in wordpress to connect. Here's one guide to install and configure ftp at ubuntu

http://gabrielmagana.com/2014/11/installing-ftp-server-vsftpd-on-an-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-14-04-host/

Comment: I did not install an FTP server. I should have mentioned that I was connecting via SFTP not just FTP.

Comment: I guess the /var/www is not accessible by the user. If you can change the project dir to ubuntu home folder, the permission should work them

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can set the owner of the directory to www-data. Then add user Ubuntu to the www-data group.

```
sudo adduser www-data ubuntu
```

Comment: I am told that `The user 'www-data' is already a member of 'ubuntu'.`

Comment: You can confirm it by saying `groups ubuntu`. It will tell you the groups Ubuntu is belongs to

Comment: `www-data` is indeed within the ubuntu group (along with several others). Running the suggested `adduser` command alone hasn't changed anything or resolved the issue yet.